# How to eliminate signs in txt file and dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following txt file (T1):

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{\"OV147\"}>" 0.286903266331658
"2" "<{\"OV148\"}>" 0.121309673366834
"3" "<{\"OV188\"}>" 0.0820508793969849
"4" "<{\"OV191\"}>" 0.0793812814070352
```

I would like to get the following:

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{OV147}>" 0.286903266331658
"2" "<{OV148}>" 0.121309673366834
"3" "<{OV188}>" 0.0820508793969849
"4" "<{OV191}>" 0.0793812814070352
```

In addition I have a `s` dataframe and I want to write it to file in the previous format. What to change in `s`:

```
                                    sequence    support
1                                <{"OV147"}> 0.28690327
2                                <{"OV148"}> 0.12130967
3                                <{"OV188"}> 0.08205088
4                                <{"OV191"}> 0.07938128
```

When I use read.table I get the following:

```
a<- read.table(header=TRUE, text=' "sequence" "support"
"1" "<{\"OV147\"}>" 0.286903266331658
  "2" "<{\"OV148\"}>" 0.121309673366834
  "3" "<{\"OV188\"}>" 0.0820508793969849
  "4" "<{\"OV191\"}>" 0.0793812814070352
', quote = '')
```

I get:

```
> a
      X.sequence.          X.support.
"1" "<{"OV147"}>"   0.286903266331658
"2" "<{"OV148"}>"   0.121309673366834
"3" "<{"OV188"}>"  0.0820508793969849
"4" "<{"OV191"}>"  0.0793812814070352
```

Comment: did you try anything? `read.table` with `quote = ''` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub()` with the appropriate regular expression to adjust the column names, and then the string in `sequence`:

```
names(a) <- sub("X\\.(.*)\\.", "\\1",  names(a))
a$sequence <- sub('<\\{"(.*)"\\}>', "<{\\1}>", a$sequence)

# sequence             support
# "1" "<{OV147}>"   0.286903266331658
# "2" "<{OV148}>"   0.121309673366834
# "3" "<{OV188}>"  0.0820508793969849
# "4" "<{OV191}>"  0.0793812814070352
```

If you want to write it back to a text file, you could for instance do

```
sink("t2.txt")
a
sink()
```

You can read more about `sub()` by typing `?sub`.

Comment: Thanks @hfty! Why in the last character of get "  - 
"4" "<{OV191}>" 0.0793812814070352"

Comment: @Avi I think you typed in an extra `"` at the line 4 of your `read.table` example, which was not in the original text file?

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` will do this job.

```
a$sequence <- gsub('"', "", a$sequence)
```